# Quantization of a spin-1 field canonical commutator

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, commutator, gauge

This is a question regarding the spin-1 massive field commutator $[A_i(\mathbf{x},t),\Pi_j(\mathbf{y},t)]$, where $\Pi$ is the conjugate field and $A^\mu$ is the four-potential. My result was,
$$[A_i(\mathbf{x},t),\Pi_j(\mathbf{y},t)]=-i \left(\delta_{ij}-\frac{\nabla_i \nabla_j}{m^2}\right)\delta^3(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}).$$
One of my textbooks says it should be equal to, $[A_i(\mathbf{x},t),\Pi_j(\mathbf{y},t)]=-ig_i^j\delta^3(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y})$. But where does the second term go? Another textbook replaces the $m^2$ with $\nabla^2$ for some reason. I am using the Lorenz gauge: $\partial_\mu A^\mu=0$.

Here's the university textbook:

> [image]

Comment: Which textbooks?

Comment: @Qmechanic My university course textbook says it's $\nabla^2$. Everywhere else (for instance, http://www.quantumfieldtheory.info/website_Chap05.pdf), it's without the second term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **massless** spin $j=1$ field has
$$
[A_i(\mathbf{x},t),\Pi_j(\mathbf{y},t)]=-i \left(\delta_{ij}+\frac{\nabla_i \nabla_j}{{\color{red}\nabla^2}}\right)\delta^3(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}).
$$
while a **massive** spin $j=1$ field has
$$
[A_i(\mathbf{x},t),\Pi_j(\mathbf{y},t)]=-i \left(\delta_{ij}-\frac{\nabla_i \nabla_j}{{\color{red}m^2}}\right)\delta^3(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}).
$$

Finally, a (massless or massive) **Stückelberg** field, in the 't Hooft-Feynman gauge $\xi=1$ has
$$
[A_\mu(\mathbf{x},t),\Pi_\nu(\mathbf{y},t)]=-i \eta_{\mu\nu}\delta^3(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}).
$$

The first case is sometimes said to correspond to the **Coulomb** gauge (even though one could argue that we are *not* picking any gauge in particular, but just using the polarisation vectors as dictated by the properties of the massless representations of the Poincaré Group), while the second one is sometimes said to correspond to the unitary gauge ($\xi\to\infty$) of a Stückelberg field . This is also known as a **Proca** field.

Comment: Another good answer! So, as far as I understand, a $\xi=1$ gauge removes the $\frac{m^2(\partial_\mu A^\mu)^2}{2}$ term from the Lagrangian?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $m^2A_\mu^* A^\mu$. But I guess I have to read more, so I'll close this for now.